# copying text selenium using .text()

Tags: python, selenium

I need to scrape some text from a table, using selenium. I'm a complete novice, but thanks to Stack overflow, I was able to get to get pretty far. Now I am getting an error when using text() to copy text. Here are my codes.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/User/Downloads/chromedriver')
url = "https://aca.tampagov.net/citizenaccess/Default.aspx#"
driver.get(url)
# The website I need to check


# Click "search" at the top menu
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main_menu"]/ul/li[2]/a').click()
# Click "building permits" in the menu that follows below
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="main_menu"]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/a').click()

#change iframes
driver.switch_to.frame("ACAFrame")
# When changing iframes, I was recommended that I should use this, 
# WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='ACAFrame']")))

# but I'm now having troubles running this line so I changed it to the line like above
```

Now you can find that there's a table below. I want to copy text using a code such as:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tbody/tr[3]/td[4]').text()
```

But I get, instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-117-2a4c7f9321b5>", line 1, in <module>
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tbody/tr[3]/td[4]').text()

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: use the `text` property instead.  because `text` is a property on `WebElement`, while `text()` is a method that does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tbody/tr[3]/td[4]').text
```

instead of

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tbody/tr[3]/td[4]').text()
```

The statement `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tbody/tr[3]/td[4]').text` returns a `string`, so you don't have to add the parenthesis at the end. If you add the parenthesis, then syntax means you are *calling* it, but you can only *call*  *callable* objects, such as functions. Thus, the error.